# Check if cell iterator is valid in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a set of code I've written using the PHPExcel library. However, sometimes it works, and sometimes it crashes.

The code it specifically breaks on is the declaration of the foreach loop

```
$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
foreach ($cellIterator as $cell){  // <-- Breaks here
   // Do the Thing
}
```

Is there a good way to check if the cell iterator is valid?

Note: Error is -

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isDataSet() on null in /PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php:1195
```

Comment: Breaks in what way? What error do you get?

Comment: And have you tried the cell iterator's `valid()` method?

Comment: I was unaware of the valid() method, how's it work?

Comment: You can look at the code to see how it works, but it basically just checks to see if the current cell pointer in the row is at a position less than or equal to the highest column in the row